# Ignoring condition for a value in the list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

my function is printing `passed` if the condition becomes successful for the items on the list. if not then it will print `failed`

```
list1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16]

for n in list1:
  if 15 > n:
    print("passed")
  else:
    print("failed")
```

It is giving the correct output. for value `16` in the `list1`, it is printing `failed`

Current output:

```
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
failed
```

Is it possible that for value `16` in the `list1` also, it should ignore `failed` and print `passed` only

Expected output: printing `passed` for value `16` in the `list1`

```
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
passed
```

Comment: just add OR condition in your main condition ?

Comment: just change if statement: `if 17 > n:`

Comment: What is the original purpose of the condition `15 > n`? Why do you want to make a special exception for the value `16`? Is the exception supposed to be for *all* `16` in the list, or only the last value in the list (independent of actual value), or only to that specific position in the list (independent on actual value)? Is the value `15` still to "fail", or should it also "pass"? What is the requirements you have to make you add this special case? What is the actual problem this exception is supposed to solve? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to get passed for the 16th you might want to change the condition.

```
list1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16]
for n in list1:
    if 17 > n:
        print("passed")
    else:
        print("failed")
```

So instead of if 15 > n you should put 17 > n.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is printing passed if the element from the list is less than `15`. So that is normal that `16 > 15` so it prints `failed`. If you want to print passed for every element in the list you should use the following code:

```
for n in list1:
  if 15 > n or n == 16:
    print("passed")
  else:
    print("failed")
```

Answer (score 1):

other way is to check for certain range (15 -16 )
with `if 15 <= n <= 16:`

```
list1 = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,16]

for n in list1:
    

    if 15 <= n <= 16:
         print("passed")
    else:
        print("failed")
```